# Using sed, find mailing address in each text file and store portions of it to separate variables?

Tags: regex, linux, sed, text-processing

I have a series of text files that each contain the string "Address" twice in different parts of the file, and later the string "Subscriber Address", making for three total appearances of "Address".  Using sed, I'd like to harvest data immediately following the *first* instance of "Address" in each file while ignoring the rest.  Sometimes the full address will appear in two lines as follows...

```
Address
100 MAIN ST
STRATFORD CT 06614
```

And sometimes the address line will wrap, moving the City, State and ZIP to a third line as follows...

```
Address
NO 10 GREEN ACRES
LANE
SHELTON CT 06484
```

I'd like to store the output in variables: Address1, Address2, City, State and Zip.  Using each of the examples above, the desired outcome would be...

```
Address1=100 MAIN ST
City=STRATFORD
State=CT
Zip=06614

Address1=NO 10 GREEN ACRES
Address2=LANE
City=SHELTON
State=CT
Zip=06484
```

A suitable alternative in the second example would be to concatenate address lines 1 and 2, resulting in the following...

```
Address1=NO 10 GREEN ACRES LANE
City=SHELTON
State=CT
Zip=06484
```

I know that this is a lot to ask.  Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a bash and GNU grep? What is between two address blocks? Is there a empty line or next address block?

Comment: The most difficult part in this is to determine if address located on one, two or three lines. As far I understand, city is always a single word, state is a 2 letters and zip is 5 digits, right?

Comment: @SlavaSemushin The city may be more than one word (ex: New Haven), the state is always two letters, and the zip is always five digits.

If we had to, we could focus only on the line immediately below Address as Address1, and the first line below it that ends in two letters, followed by a space, followed by 5 numbers.  If we were to do this, we'd lose the word LANE in the second example, but this would be acceptable.

Comment: @Cyrus Yes, we have bash and GNU grep.  Running this on Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

Sed is not intended for this purpose. Sed operates on single lines only, not keeping history and such.

You could switch to e.g. an AWK clone (awk, gawk, nawk).

Comment: This sort of information is best posted as a comment to the original question. (I agree with you). Others may downvote as not answering the question. Good luck to all.

Answer (score 0):

There is my attempt to do this:

```
$ cat file
test
First Address
100 MAIN ST STRATFORD CT 06614
test
Second Address
100 MAIN ST
STRATFORD CT 06614
test
Third Address
NO 10 GREEN ACRES
LANE
SHELTON CT 06484
test
$ sed -n '/Address/{:start;N;/[^0-9]$/b start;s/\n/|/g;p}' file |
sed 1d |
sed 's/^Address|//;s| \([0-9]\+\)$|\nZip: \1|' |
sed 's| \([A-Z]\+\)$|\nState: \1|'|
sed 's/|\([^|]\+\)$/\nCity: \1/' |
sed '/^[^:]\+$/s|\(.*\)|Address: \1|;s/|/ /g'
Address: Second Address 100 MAIN ST
City: STRATFORD
State: CT
Zip: 06614
Address: Third Address NO 10 GREEN ACRES LANE
City: SHELTON
State: CT
Zip: 06484
```

(Let me not to explain how it exactly works :-))

P.S. The idea behind this loong command is to transforming file to lines with adressed only, after that we delete 1st line and continue with others. By using regular expressions we transform each addresses to required format.

Comment: I may not have explained it properly.  In a given file, there are three instances of address, but we only want to retrieve the *first* into the variables mentioned while ignoring the other instances of address.

Comment: In this case just replace `sed 1d` by `head -1` in long command.

Comment: Am I supposed to pipe the several sed lines into a single command?  Do I only need to specify the filename once, or in each section?

Comment: Yes, all commands should be in one lines and I separated them only for readability.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong.  I sent you a sample of one of my files.

Answer (score 0):

`sed -ne '/./{H;$!d;}' -e 'x;/Address/,/^$/!d' -e 's/\n/#/g;s/#Address#//' -e 's/\(.*\)#\(.*\)#\(.*\)/Address1=\1\nAddress2=\2\n\3\n/;s/\(.*\)#\(.*\)/Address1=\1\n\2\n/;s/\([a-Z]*\)\s\([a-Z][a-Z]\)\s\([0-9]\{5\}\)/City=\1\nState=\2\nZip=\3/p' addr.txt`

this flattens the addresses out and formats them then you just need to uniq them